# Apache POI Evaluate formula and update

Tags: java, apache-poi

By entering column values through JAVA Apache POI and then evaluating all the formulas, just one formula based column is not getting updated.

This picture contains the column (Column U) data format and its values that I am updating via POI Call:

[image: Column U Data Format]

Code:

```
CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("0.0%"));
style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
Cell cell2Update = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(20);
cell2Update.setCellValue("12.9%");
cell2Update.setCellStyle(style);
```

Following this picture contains the column (Column Z) data format for which the value is not getting updated:

[image: Column Z Data format]

This is the call I am making to evaluate all the column values.

```
evaluator.evaluateAll();
```

Column V,W,X,Y are getting calculated and populated in excel but Column Z with the formula `(=IFERROR((V30+W30)/(1-X30-Y30),0))` is not working.

Please help me update this formula cell Z (Calculated Sell Price).

Comment: provide more code. what you are currently providing doesn't help much

Comment: `cell2Update.setCellValue("12.9%");` is setting a string cell value instead of a numeric cell value. Thus the `IFERROR` will always leads to `0` because of type mismatch in the formula. Do using `cell2Update.setCellValue(12.9/100.0);` instead.

Comment: thanks a lot ...12.9/100.0 solved the problem .

Comment: @AxelRichter: please respond to below query . Thanks